# sed case insensitive match not working

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to match a word (which is actually a table alias) in an sql file and replacing it's column name with a different column name.

```
sed -ie s/$alias.${act_cols[a]}/$alias.$third_ele/gI $sql_file
```

The problem is that the `I` option for case insensitive match seems not working. Here `$alias` contains value "red1" and `$act_cols` is an array of columns and `act_cols[a]` we can assume the value as "NAME" and `$third_ele` contains the replacement column name say "COLUMN_01".

The file contains alias as RED1 (in caps) at some places, for these instances the column names are not replaced.

e.g. `red1.NAME` is correctly replaced as `red1.COLUMN_01`
but `RED1.NAME` is not replaced with `RED1.COLUMN_01`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `I` is not a standard flag for `s`. Which sed are you using? Which OS is this?

Comment: I would say it's /i instead of /I

Comment: @darxmurf I think `/i` and `/I` is same and both works for me at other places. Well, i tried `/i` also but still same issue.

Comment: @muru my current shell is `/bin/bash (-bash)` and GNU sed 4.2.2

Answer (score 2):

I think only GNU sed has I/i modifier .

Just , if your sed doesn't support I/i , you can use it like below to avoid 
case sense.

Assign the `alias` variable like below and use `sed` as :

```
$ alias="[Rr][Ee][Dd]1"
$ echo "RED1.NAME and red1.NAME and red1 and Red1" | sed -e "s/\($alias\).NAME/\1.COLUMN1/g"
RED1.COLUMN1 and red1.COLUMN1 and red1 and Red1
```

OR **if `alias` variable is dynamic , you can use `perl` or `awk` like below;**

```
$ alias="red1"
$ act_cols="NAME"
$ third_ele="COLUMN1"
$ echo "RED1.NAME and red1.NAME and red1 and Red1" | perl -pe "s/($alias).$act_cols/\1.$third_ele/gi"
RED1.COLUMN1 and red1.COLUMN1 and red1 and Red1
```

Using awk:

```
$ echo $alias
red1
$ echo "RED1.NAME and red1.NAME and red1 and Red1" | awk -v value=$alias 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} { gsub(value".NAME",value".COLUMN1");print }'
red1.COLUMN1 and red1.COLUMN1 and red1 and Red1
```

Comment: The variable is actually in a loop and has different values, I just cannot substitute some value to it.

Comment: @MohammedArif : Oh , yeah then you may try awk , if any red1 ex:`"RED1 or red1"`  can be replaced as `red1`

Comment: @MohammedArif : Try `perl` and with -i option , you can do in-place edit in file like `sed`